# isAdded() in DialogFragment in onCreateDialog()

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my `DialogFragment`, in `OnCreateDialog()`, i am testing whether the Fragment has been added to Activity using `isAdded()` and then doing something.

So is it safe to call `isAdded()` from `onCreateDialog()`. Is the Fragment added to activity by then? I am not getting any exceptions, but is it the correct section to call `isAdded()`? Or it should it be called from only `onActivityCreated()`?

Nothing is mentioned in the documentation about this.

Comment: isAdded mostly called on the instance of a fragment to check if it is added or not .

Comment: I know what isAdded() is used for. But where it should be called from?

Comment: thats what I said. read it again.

Comment: So only while creating new instance, i should check that?

Comment: take you have a datepicker fragment and you want to open it on button click. on button click you create an instance of some datepicker fragment and checks if it is already added, if it is then no need to open a fragment, otherwise show it.

Comment: But suppose i dont check this and always create a new instance. Then isAdded() should always return true in datepickerfragment. Isnt it?

Comment: No, because at that time instance is already created. and have a different memory address so different object.

Comment: I didnt get your last point. Can you please explain slightly more?

Comment: Also what is called first? OnActivityCreated() or onCreateDialog()?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating